# Intuition for estimating population standard deviation

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, estimation, intuition

I know *how* to estimate population standard deviation using a chi square distribution, but I don't know *why* it works. I'd like to have an intuition for the why.

I've tried googling around. I always find descriptions of the how, not the why. My guess as to what's going on:

- The distribution of sample SDs is normally distributed (sorta makes sense, but I don't really understand why).
- If they're normally distributed, when you square it, it becomes a chi square distribution with 1 degree of freedom (this makes sense to me). Since SD squared is Var, we have a chi square distribution of Vars.
- From there, once we have a distribution, we can say that X% of the sample Vars are within a range (U, L).
- There's some sort of adjustment, because sample Var is a biased estimator of population Var.
- Where do multiple degrees of freedom come in to play?

Comment: "I know how to estimate population standard deviation using a chi square distribution" — Exactly what procedure are you referring to? Are you asking a question about [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel's_correction)?

Comment: Squareroot((n-1)(s^2)/chi value)

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran's_theorem#Sample_mean_and_sample_variance) and [a bit lower down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran's_theorem#Estimation_of_variance)

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe your rationale is correct.  If $X$ has a normal distribution then its sample variance is proportional to a chi-square distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, where $n$ is the sample size. So the chi-square distribution can be used to draw inferences about the population variance and hence also the standard deviation. But if $X$ is not normally distributed there is no reason to use the chi-square distribution.